# Percentages in key of an array

Tags: php, arrays, drupal-7

I'm currently reading through some code in a drupal module and have come across the following in an associative array.

```
$this->replacements = array(
      '%field' => $this->instance['label'],
      '%bundle' => $bundles[$this->instance['entity_type']][$this->instance['bundle']]['label'],
);
```

What does the % in the key mean or is it just a string label

Comment: It is a string label.

Comment: Just part of the key name as far as PHP is concerned. I'm not familiar with drupal naming conventions, so it may have some special significance in drupal

Comment: Looking through the code a bit further there is a function in drupal called t which renders text. so the following line t('Number of %bundle entities', $replacements) I guess replaces %bundle with the value of the key %bundle in the array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think its just sting label.

```
$a = array("%name" => "pugazh", "vaalue" => "value");
print_r($a);
```

If you try like this in corephp it will return an output like this

```
Array ( [%name] => pugazh [vaalue] => value )
```

But i don't know what its mean in drupal.